# Understanding tentative definitions in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, multiple-definition-error

I know that tentative definition is like

```
int i;
int i;
```

and they are combined while linking 
and real definition is like

```
int i=5;
```

and used once ,but what is the point of having many tentative definitions in the code ***(why I'll need to declare it twice?)***
and why repeated  tentative definition give errors in ***C++*** and works fine in **C**

Comment: 1) No need. 2) C and C++ are different languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because C++ doesn't have tentative definitions. That is a C language feature that C++ does not have.

So when you write `int i;`, that is *a real definition* (without an initialiser attached). Per the one definition rule, you may only have one definition (!).

As for an example of why you'd *want* to use them in C, honestly I can't think of one. Maybe that's why C++ didn't bother!

Note that you can still *declare* stuff as often as you like. For objects, you'll need to use `extern` to signal this intention:

```
extern int x;
extern int x;
extern int x;

int x = 0;
```